# EPPlus 5.0: Why is Excel file so big?

Tags: .net-core, epplus

I have an EPPlus package added on to a .Net Core 3.0 project. After pulling data from a database and displaying it on-screen, I have an option for the user to pass the model to an action that builds an Excel xlsx file and downloads it. The file contains a few worksheets, but each sheet contains 36 rows of 6 columns (or less). This generates an Excel file over 320MB and takes over 8 minutes to build.

```
byte[] fileContents;

            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

            using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(viewModel.ReportDate);

                worksheet.Cells["a1"].Value = "Reimbursement Closing Report";
                worksheet.Cells["a2"].Value = "Billing " + viewModel.FiscalDate.Month + " - " + viewModel.FiscalDate.Year;
                worksheet.Cells["a4"].Value = "Total Billed Services";
                worksheet.Cells["b4"].Value = "DR Svcs";
                worksheet.Cells["c4"].Value = "MH";
                worksheet.Cells["d4"].Value = "TCOMI";
                worksheet.Cells["e4"].Value = "Terrell";
                worksheet.Cells["f4"].Value = "Rockwall";
                worksheet.Cells["g4"].Value = "Greenville";
                worksheet.Cells["h4"].Value = "ACT TR/GV";
                worksheet.Cells["i4"].Value = "MH PASR";
                worksheet.Cells["j4"].Value = "CD";
                worksheet.Cells["k4"].Value = "IDDP";
                worksheet.Cells["l4"].Value = "PASSR / Homes";
                worksheet.Cells["m4"].Value = "HAB Coord";
                worksheet.Cells["n4"].Value = "IDD North";
                worksheet.Cells["o4"].Value = "IDD South";
                worksheet.Cells["b5"].Value = viewModel.DRTotal;
                worksheet.Cells["c5"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.MHTotal;
                worksheet.Cells["d5"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.TCOOMITotal;
                worksheet.Cells["e5"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.TerrellTotal;
                worksheet.Cells["f5"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.RockwallTotal;
                worksheet.Cells["g5"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.GreenvilleTotal;
                worksheet.Cells["h5"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.TerrellACTTotal + " / " + viewModel.MCDSvc.GVACTTotal;
                worksheet.Cells["i5"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.PASRTotal;
                worksheet.Cells["j5"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.CDTotal;
                worksheet.Cells["k5"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.IDD2800Total;
                worksheet.Cells["l5"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.PASRR7900Total + " / " + viewModel.MCDSvc.Homes9000Total;
                worksheet.Cells["m5"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.HABCoordTotal;
                worksheet.Cells["n5"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.IDDNorthTotal;
                worksheet.Cells["o5"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.IDDSouthTotal;

                worksheet.Cells["g7"].Value = "Region 9 & 10:";
                worksheet.Cells["g8"].Value = "Spec Ther:";
                worksheet.Cells["h7"].Value = viewModel.MCDSvc.Reg910Total;
                worksheet.Cells["h8"].Value = viewModel.Garner.Total;
                worksheet.Cells["a7"].Value = "Write-Offs";
                worksheet.Cells["b7"].Value = 0.00M;
                worksheet.Cells["b8"].Value = viewModel.AllTotal;
                worksheet.Cells["c9"].Value = "*Includes DR Svcs";
                worksheet.SelectedRange["a1:o4"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                worksheet.SelectedRange["a:o"].AutoFitColumns();
                worksheet.SelectedRange["a1:o4"].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                worksheet.SelectedRange["a1:o4"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue);
                worksheet.View.ShowGridLines = true;
                worksheet.SelectedRange["b5:o8"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "\\$###,###,##0.00";

                var worksheet3 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DR Card Svcs");
                worksheet3.Cells["a1"].Value = "Monthly Reimbursement Report";
                worksheet3.Cells["a2"].Value = "Billing " + viewModel.FiscalDate.Month + " - " + viewModel.FiscalDate.Year;
                worksheet3.Cells["a4"].Value = "Dr. Services";

                worksheet3.Cells["c4"].Value = viewModel.ReportDate;
                worksheet3.Cells["a6"].Value = "Medicaid";
                worksheet3.Cells["a6"].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Magenta);
                worksheet3.Cells["a6"].Style.Font.Bold = true;

                worksheet3.Cells["a7"].Value = "Total amount billed for doctor services:";
                worksheet3.Cells["c7"].Value = viewModel.DR.FirstOrDefault().Balance;

                worksheet3.Cells["a7"].Value = "Base (" + (viewModel.MCDPercent * 100) + "%)";
                worksheet3.Cells["c7"].Value = viewModel.DR.FirstOrDefault().Balance * viewModel.MCDPercent;

                worksheet3.Cells["a7"].Value = "State (" + (100 - (viewModel.MCDPercent * 100)) + "%)";
                worksheet3.Cells["c7"].Value = 100 - (viewModel.DR.FirstOrDefault().Balance * viewModel.MCDPercent);

                worksheet3.Cells["a9"].Value = "Total Dr. Services:";
                worksheet3.Cells["a9"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                worksheet3.Cells["c9"].Value = viewModel.DRTotal;

                worksheet3.SelectedRange["a1:c4"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                worksheet3.SelectedRange["a:c"].AutoFitColumns();
                worksheet3.SelectedRange["a1:c4"].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                worksheet3.SelectedRange["a1:c4"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue);
                worksheet3.View.ShowGridLines = true;
                worksheet3.SelectedRange["c4:c50"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "\\$###,###,##0.00";

                foreach (var location in viewModel.MCDSvc.Loc)
                {
                    var worksheet4 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(location.Location);
                    worksheet4.Cells["a1"].Value = "Monthly Reimbursement Report";
                    worksheet4.Cells["a2"].Value = "Billing " + viewModel.FiscalDate.Month + " - " + viewModel.FiscalDate.Year;
                    worksheet4.Cells["a3"].Value = location.Location;
                    worksheet4.Cells["b5"].Value = viewModel.ReportDate;

                    var row = 6;
                    var gtotal = 0.00M;

                    foreach (var paysrc in location.PaySrc)
                    {
                        worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = paysrc.PaySource;
                        worksheet4.SelectedRange["a" + row + ":a" + row].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                        worksheet4.SelectedRange["a" + row + ":a" + row].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Magenta);
                        row++;

                        foreach (var ageGrp in paysrc.AgeGroup)
                        {
                            if (ageGrp.AgeGroup == "Adult")
                            {
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Case Management:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = ageGrp.CaseMng;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 1)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Rehab:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 1)].Value = ageGrp.Rehab;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 2)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Card Services:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 2)].Value = ageGrp.CardSvcs;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 3)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for the month:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 3)].Value = ageGrp.Total;
                                gtotal = gtotal + ageGrp.Total;
                                row = row + 5;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Case Management:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = ageGrp.CaseMng;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 1)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Rehab:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 1)].Value = ageGrp.Rehab;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 2)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Card Services:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 2)].Value = ageGrp.CardSvcs;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 3)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for the month:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 3)].Value = ageGrp.Total;
                                gtotal = gtotal + ageGrp.Total;
                                row = row + 5;
                            }

                            worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Base (" + (viewModel.MCDPercent*100) + "%)";
                            worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                            row = row + 2;

                            if (ageGrp.AgeGroup == "Adult")
                            {
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Case Management:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = Decimal.Round(ageGrp.CaseMng * viewModel.MCDPercent);
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 1)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Rehab:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 1)].Value = ageGrp.Rehab;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 2)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Card Services:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 2)].Value = ageGrp.CardSvcs;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 3)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for the month:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 3)].Value = ageGrp.Total;
                                gtotal = gtotal + ageGrp.Total;
                                row = row + 5;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Case Management:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = ageGrp.CaseMng;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 1)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Rehab:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 1)].Value = ageGrp.Rehab;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 2)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Card Services:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 2)].Value = ageGrp.CardSvcs;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 3)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for the month:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 3)].Value = ageGrp.Total;
                                gtotal = gtotal + ageGrp.Total;
                                row = row + 5;
                            }

                            worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "State (" + (100 - (viewModel.MCDPercent * 100)) + "%)";
                            worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                            row = row + 2;

                            if (ageGrp.AgeGroup == "Adult")
                            {
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Case Management:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = Decimal.Round(ageGrp.CaseMng * viewModel.MCDPercent);
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 1)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Rehab:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 1)].Value = ageGrp.Rehab;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 2)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for the month:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 2)].Value = ageGrp.Total;
                                gtotal = gtotal + ageGrp.Total;
                                row = row + 5;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Case Management:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = ageGrp.CaseMng;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 1)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Rehab:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 1)].Value = ageGrp.Rehab;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 2)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for the month:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 2)].Value = ageGrp.Total;
                                gtotal = gtotal + ageGrp.Total;
                                row = row + 5;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total amount billed for " + location.Location + ":";
                    worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = gtotal;

                    worksheet4.SelectedRange["a1:c5"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    worksheet4.SelectedRange["a:c"].AutoFitColumns();
                    worksheet4.SelectedRange["a1:c5"].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    worksheet4.SelectedRange["a1:c5"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue);
                    worksheet4.View.ShowGridLines = true;
                    worksheet4.SelectedRange["b7:i"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "\\$###,###,##0.00";
                }

                var worksheet13 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("1302-1303");
                worksheet13.Cells["a1"].Value = "Monthly Reimbursement Report";
                worksheet13.Cells["a2"].Value = "Billing " + viewModel.FiscalDate.Month + " - " + viewModel.FiscalDate.Year;
                worksheet13.Cells["a3"].Value = "1302-1303 Breakdown";
                worksheet13.Cells["b5"].Value = viewModel.ReportDate;

                var RegBreak = viewModel.Reg910;
                var rowNum = 6;

                foreach (var plan in RegBreak.Plan)
                {
                    worksheet13.Cells["a" + rowNum].Value = plan.PlanName;
                    worksheet13.SelectedRange["a" + rowNum + ":a" + rowNum].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    worksheet13.SelectedRange["a" + rowNum + ":a" + rowNum].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Magenta);
                    worksheet13.Cells["b" + rowNum].Value = plan.Acct;

                    foreach (var server in plan.Servers)
                    {
                        worksheet13.Cells["c" + rowNum].Value = server.ServerName;
                        worksheet13.Cells["d" + rowNum].Value = server.CostCenter;
                        worksheet13.Cells["e" + rowNum].Value = server.Amount;
                        rowNum = rowNum + 1;
                    }
                }

                worksheet13.Cells["a" + (rowNum + 1)].Value = "Total amount billed :";
                worksheet13.Cells["b" + (rowNum + 1)].Value = RegBreak.Reg9Total;
                worksheet13.Cells["a" + (rowNum + 2)].Value = "Total amount billed :";
                worksheet13.Cells["b" + (rowNum + 2)].Value = RegBreak.Reg10Total;
                worksheet13.Cells["a" + (rowNum + 3)].Value = "Total amount billed :";
                worksheet13.Cells["a" + (rowNum + 3)].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                worksheet13.Cells["b" + (rowNum + 3)].Value = RegBreak.Reg9Total + RegBreak.Reg10Total;

                worksheet13.SelectedRange["a1:c5"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                worksheet13.SelectedRange["a:c"].AutoFitColumns();
                worksheet13.SelectedRange["a1:c5"].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                worksheet13.SelectedRange["a1:c5"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue);
                worksheet13.View.ShowGridLines = true;
                worksheet13.SelectedRange["e4:i50"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "\\$###,###,##0.00";
                worksheet13.SelectedRange["b24:b30"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "\\$###,###,##0.00";

                fileContents = await package.GetAsByteArrayAsync();
```

How is a file containing so little data so huge? I have tried commenting out AutoFitColumns, Gridlines, colors, etc. It takes only a few seconds to process the worksheets, but once it gets to the last line to set everything as a byte array, everything stops for several minutes.

```
fileContents = await package.GetAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Is there something I am missing that is causing the file to balloon to such enormous sizes?

Answer (score 0):

After spending a couple of hours trying a few other iterations of this code, I arrived at a variant that not only makes smaller Excel files but is lightning fast compared to the code above. Apparently, it has to do with the `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (var location in viewModel.MCDSvc.Loc)
                {
                    var worksheet4 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(location.Location);
                    worksheet4.Cells["a1"].Value = "Monthly Reimbursement Report";
                    worksheet4.Cells["a2"].Value = "Billing " + viewModel.FiscalDate.Month + " - " + viewModel.FiscalDate.Year;
                    worksheet4.Cells["a3"].Value = location.Location;
                    worksheet4.Cells["b5"].Value = viewModel.ReportDate;

                    var row = 6;
                    var gtotal = 0.00M;

                    foreach (var paysrc in location.PaySrc)
                    {
                        worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = paysrc.PaySource;
                        worksheet4.SelectedRange["a" + row + ":a" + row].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                        worksheet4.SelectedRange["a" + row + ":a" + row].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Magenta);
                        row++;

                        foreach (var ageGrp in paysrc.AgeGroup)
                        {
                            if (ageGrp.AgeGroup == "Adult")
                            {
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Case Management:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = ageGrp.CaseMng;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 1)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Rehab:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 1)].Value = ageGrp.Rehab;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 2)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Card Services:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 2)].Value = ageGrp.CardSvcs;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 3)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for the month:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 3)].Value = ageGrp.Total;
                                gtotal = gtotal + ageGrp.Total;
                                row = row + 5;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Case Management:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = ageGrp.CaseMng;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 1)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Rehab:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 1)].Value = ageGrp.Rehab;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 2)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Card Services:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 2)].Value = ageGrp.CardSvcs;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 3)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for the month:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 3)].Value = ageGrp.Total;
                                gtotal = gtotal + ageGrp.Total;
                                row = row + 5;
                            }

                            worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Base (" + (viewModel.MCDPercent*100) + "%)";
                            worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                            row = row + 2;

                            if (ageGrp.AgeGroup == "Adult")
                            {
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Case Management:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = Decimal.Round(ageGrp.CaseMng * viewModel.MCDPercent);
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 1)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Rehab:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 1)].Value = ageGrp.Rehab;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 2)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Card Services:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 2)].Value = ageGrp.CardSvcs;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 3)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for the month:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 3)].Value = ageGrp.Total;
                                gtotal = gtotal + ageGrp.Total;
                                row = row + 5;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Case Management:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = ageGrp.CaseMng;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 1)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Rehab:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 1)].Value = ageGrp.Rehab;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 2)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Card Services:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 2)].Value = ageGrp.CardSvcs;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 3)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for the month:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 3)].Value = ageGrp.Total;
                                gtotal = gtotal + ageGrp.Total;
                                row = row + 5;
                            }

                            worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "State (" + (100 - (viewModel.MCDPercent * 100)) + "%)";
                            worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                            row = row + 2;

                            if (ageGrp.AgeGroup == "Adult")
                            {
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Case Management:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = Decimal.Round(ageGrp.CaseMng * viewModel.MCDPercent);
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 1)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for Rehab:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 1)].Value = ageGrp.Rehab;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 2)].Value = "Total ADULT amount billed for the month:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 2)].Value = ageGrp.Total;
                                gtotal = gtotal + ageGrp.Total;
                                row = row + 5;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Case Management:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = ageGrp.CaseMng;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 1)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for Rehab:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 1)].Value = ageGrp.Rehab;
                                worksheet4.Cells["a" + (row + 2)].Value = "Total C/A amount billed for the month:";
                                worksheet4.Cells["b" + (row + 2)].Value = ageGrp.Total;
                                gtotal = gtotal + ageGrp.Total;
                                row = row + 5;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Value = "Total amount billed for " + location.Location + ":";
                    worksheet4.Cells["a" + row].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    worksheet4.Cells["b" + row].Value = gtotal;

                    worksheet4.SelectedRange["a1:c5"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    worksheet4.SelectedRange["a:c"].AutoFitColumns();
                    worksheet4.SelectedRange["a1:c5"].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    worksheet4.SelectedRange["a1:c5"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue);
                    worksheet4.View.ShowGridLines = true;
                    worksheet4.SelectedRange["b7:i"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "\\$###,###,##0.00";
                }
```

If I replace this with code for each worksheet instead of the loop to build each worksheet, I get a file under 17MB and under a minute to build it.

While this is one solution to the problem, I don't think it's good code to have to build out something that can more easily be done with a simple loop. Anyone with a better solution?